# json data mapping of avro union

Tags: json, avro

I wonder if the incoming json payload, like this, **json sample version 1**

```
{
    "name": "Alyssa",
    "favorite_number": 7,
    "favorite_color": "blue"
}
```

what's the easy way to add the Data Type and get the updated json data to accommodate the Avro Union requirement. **json sample version 2**

```
{
    "name": "Alyssa",
    "favorite_number": {
        "int": 7
    },
    "favorite_color": null
}
```

**The Avro Schema is :**

```
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "name",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "avro.java.string": "String"
                            },
                            "default": "1234567890"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "favorite_number",
                            "type": ["null", "Int"],
                            "doc": "The code for originating channel/consumer",
                            "default": null
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "favorite_color",
                            "type": ["null","String"],
                            "doc": "The communication language selected by customer.",
                            "default": null
                        }
                    ]
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any specific error in the conversion process?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the thing is i have to use the  json sample version 2 to make the json sample compatible with Avro schema, while most of time, i received the json sample format , like version 1.  i wonder what's the best way to convert json version 1 to version 2.

Comment: Avro doesn't provide any such tools, and I'm not really sure it cares if you use `7` or `{"int: 7}`